# YII - how we can get the name of the method in init() function in controller?

Tags: php, session, yii

In a YII work, I have an init() function which checks whether the session is set if not redirect to login page.

The problem is that the "login" action is also in the same controller, so it is creating an infinite loop.  If I can get the method name in init() function, I can solve this issue.

How I can get the method name in init() function?

Comment: Would `__FUNCTION__` work for your situation? http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: @SeanNieuwoudt hi am using YII ... i want to get the action name which is called  not the function name..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current Controller

```
Yii::app()->controller->id
```

and
Current Action

```
Yii::app()->controller->action->id
```

To check action id in all functions other than init(), because init function initializes the controller...

So the solution for your problem will be let the request come to the actionLogin in your login controller..and there you check if session is not check redirect him from where he is coming..else perform the login action..That way you'll not face loop problem..

Comment: This is not working in init() function it throws an error... It works fyn in other functions

Comment: Error : Trying to get property of non-object