# How can i get action id and controller id in init() or constructor() method in yii

Tags: php, yii

i want to get action name and controller name in init() method or construct() method in controller. for example if i call create method i should get create as action name in init() or constructor() method. is it possible in Yii ? please do help.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921595/yii-how-we-can-get-the-name-of-the-method-in-init-function-in-controller?rq=1

Comment: Hey Peter i had saw this link before, i am lokking for somethink diffrent. I got an answer.. anyways, Thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of the method as shown:

```
public function afterAction($action){
        $result=$action->getid();
        echo $result; // you will get the action name
        echo Yii::app()->getController()->getId(); //get the controller name
}
```

Or simply make use of this code in init()

```
 echo Yii::app()->controller->id;
 echo Yii::app()->controller->action->id;
```

Comment: Hey Ninad, Thanks for reply. I m able to use Yii::app()->controller->id; statement in init() method but Yii::app()->controller->action->id; this statement is giving error..